# jsvc (tomcat) does not daemonize properly when run with backticks and then defuncts

Tags: perl, bash, tomcat

In debian lenny, when running /etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 start, it runs jsvc and expects it to daemonize itself.

From a simple bash shell, this works fine.

However, from a script, this gets completely stuck:

For example, the following works like a charm:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $cmd = '/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5  start';
system($cmd);
```

However, the following gets stuck as jsvc does not daemonize:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $cmd = '/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5  start';
`$cmd`;
```

It also gets stuck when running it using backticks in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD='/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5  start'
`$CMD`
```

Is this a bug in jsvc? Any idea why this works in a shell or using system() , but not using backticks? I am actually getting defunct/zombie processes because of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch -- for a job to become a daemon it needs to close any file descriptors that were opened in its parent process. Perhaps this is easier to do with `system` than with backticks/`readpipe`, though I can't come up with any good reasons why that would be so. What if you used the backticks like:

```
`$CMD < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1`
```

Answer (score 0):

Backticks will evaluate to the output of the command, if there's lots of data, you may fill the buffer.  No need to use the backticks if you don't want to evaluate or catpure the output in the script itself.

In example, this bash script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="/etc/init.d/tomcat5.5 start"
# note no backticks
$CMD
```

Also please define "daemonize"? You want this `nohup`'d and asynchronous?